# C# Decrypt emails by reading keys on smart card

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, smartcard

One of my client needs a tool to decrypt their emails.

They are using smart card for encryption/decryption.

As of now they are using a tool which asks them to enter their PUBLIC KEY. After giving a valid PUBLIC KEY, combination of PUBLIC and PRIVATE KEYS on SMART CARD will help them to decrypt their emails.

We are working on a tool which could be a windows service(which runs in the background) and decrypt all the emails with our prompting the user for public key again and again.

We are using C# to develop this tool and from the blogs I got to know that we need to Microsoft CSP to achieve this functionality. I think the below code will be able to use the smart card container and read the private key. But I am not sure how to provide the public key to this and decrypt the email.

```
CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(1, "Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider");
// CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(1, "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider");
csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer;

// Initialize an RSACryptoServiceProvider object using 
// the CspParameters object.
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);
```

Can anybody correct me if I am in a wrong direction? And also please shed some light to proceed further.

Comment: You generally need a private key / certificate combination to decrypt mail. The certificate should be bound to the private key, otherwise the private key cannot be found. You don't need a public key to decrypt of course. Otherwise your "implementation" lacks depth. If you think the above code is able to use the smart card container then try and do something with the smart card - find a certificate that is stored on it. Then try and use the private key associated with it.

Comment: @owlstead thanks for your reply. Could you please guide me to find out the associated certificate with the smart card?