# C# reading a certificate on Smart card

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, smartcard

I was looking for an advise on how to decrypt the emails using smart card. And I have posted a [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189138/c-sharp-decrypt-emails-by-reading-keys-on-smart-card) here about the same. Mr Owlstead advised me to use the certificates to decrypt which normally available with smart card. Now I got struck at the point how would I be able to use the certificate to get the key and decrypt the emails. So I have tried the below code but I am getting Keyset not present exception. Can anybody help?

```
public static void DecryptContent(byte[] data)
        {
            X509Store st = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            st.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection col = st.Certificates;

            X509Certificate2 card = null;
            // X509Certificate2Collection sel = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(col, "Certificates", "Select one to sign", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);

            if (col.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)
                {
                    var cert = col[i];

                    // Log cert.FriendlyName
                    DecryptContent(data,cert);
                }
            }

            st.Close();
        }

        public static void DecryptContent(byte[] data, X509Certificate2 certificate)
        {
            try
            {
                RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
                rsa.Decrypt(data, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                   // Log error info.
            }
        }
```